# Search box to email membership details

Tags: civimember, caldera-forms

I think I can do this with CiviRules, but my reading has left me a bit confused. Here is what I would like:

A search box on our Wordpress website. Upon a website visitor entering an email into that search box, the system would send an email to the entered address with the membership status of any found members.

I have built forms with Caldera forms, so I think maybe a combination of CiviRules and Caldera forms might work.

CiviCRM 5.20.2 on Wordpress 5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think you can setup caldera form to create an activity of type X in Civi and than have Civirule to send email (using [email api](https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api) extension) when activity of type X is created.

You can use [Civi token](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civitoken) to include memberships details in email message.

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks, shall try this and report back with a specific todo